# Ray Tracing F# - Missing triangles creates holes in figure: Hit properly?

Tags: f#, raytracing, kdtree

I have worked on this quite a while and is stuck with this bug.

We have build a ray-tracer in F# for a school project. (Link explaining Ray tracer: https://blog.frogslayer.com/kd-trees-for-faster-ray-tracing-with-triangles/)

We have a made hit function for triangles, boundingboxes, a KD tree to handle figures with thousands of triangles, such as the Stanford Bunny and a traverse algorithm for the KD tree.

We have debugged both the creation of the KD tree, made sure to add a epsilon value for float points and checked that duplicates between the boundingboxes are not removed. We are certain that we split the list of shapes in the scene corretly, but we get "holes" in the figure we try to render.

This is our KD tree implementation and I've attached pictures of the holes:

[Stanford Bunny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StL6t.png)

[Helix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBlM9.png)

```
module TmKdtree

open Point
open Shapes

type BoundingBox = BasicShape.BoundingBox 
type Shape = BasicShape.Shape

type TmKdtree =
    | Leaf of BasicShape.Triangle list * BoundingBox 
    | Node of BasicShape.Triangle list * TmKdtree * TmKdtree * BoundingBox  * (string*Point)

let epsilon = 0.001

//Making a boundingbox for the KD-tree, by finding max H point in the boundingboxlist and min l point in the boundingbox list. 
let mkKdBbox (shapes : BasicShape.Triangle list) : BoundingBox =
    let shapeX = List.map(fun x -> x:> Shape) shapes
    let sbbox = List.map (fun (c:Shape) -> c.getBounding().Value) shapeX
    let bL = List.map (fun (b:BasicShape.BoundingBox) -> b.getL) sbbox
    let bH = List.map (fun (b:BasicShape.BoundingBox) -> b.getH) sbbox

    let minX = List.minBy (fun x -> Point.getX x) bL
    let minY = List.minBy (fun x -> Point.getY x) bL
    let minZ = List.minBy (fun x -> Point.getZ x) bL

    let maxX = List.maxBy (fun x -> Point.getX x) bH
    let maxY = List.maxBy (fun x -> Point.getY x) bH
    let maxZ = List.maxBy (fun x -> Point.getZ x) bH
    {p1=(mkPoint (Point.getX minX - epsilon) (Point.getY minY - epsilon) (Point.getZ minZ - epsilon) ) 
                                 ; p2=(mkPoint (Point.getX maxX + epsilon) (Point.getY maxY + epsilon) (Point.getZ maxZ + epsilon) )}

//Splitting existing boundingbox according to left and right list of shapes
let BoundingBoxL (bbox:BoundingBox) axis midp : BoundingBox = 
    match axis with
    | "x" -> {p1 = bbox.getL - epsilon; p2 = Point.mkPoint ((Point.getX midp)) ((Point.getY (bbox.getH))) ((Point.getZ (bbox.getH))) + epsilon}
    | "y" -> {p1 = bbox.getL - epsilon; p2 = Point.mkPoint (Point.getX (bbox.getH)) ((Point.getY midp)+epsilon) ((Point.getZ (bbox.getH))) + epsilon }
    | "z" -> {p1 = bbox.getL - epsilon; p2 = Point.mkPoint (Point.getX (bbox.getH)) (Point.getY (bbox.getH)) (Point.getZ midp) + epsilon}

let BoundingBoxR (bbox:BoundingBox) axis midp : BoundingBox = 
    match axis with
    | "x" -> {p1 = (Point.mkPoint (Point.getX midp) (Point.getY (bbox.getL)) (Point.getZ (bbox.getL))) - epsilon; p2 = bbox.getH + epsilon}
    | "y" -> {p1 = (Point.mkPoint (Point.getX (bbox.getL)) (Point.getY midp) (Point.getZ (bbox.getL))) - epsilon; p2 = bbox.getH + epsilon}
    | "z" -> {p1 = (Point.mkPoint (Point.getX (bbox.getL)) (Point.getY (bbox.getL)) (Point.getZ midp)) - epsilon; p2 = bbox.getH + epsilon}


//Get left node
let getLeft s = 
   match s with
    | Node(_,l,_,_,_) -> l
    | Leaf(_,_) as leaf -> leaf 

let getRight s = 
    match s with
    | Node(_,_,r,_,_) -> r
    | Leaf(_,_) as leaf -> leaf


//Get the triangle list
let getShapes s = 
    match s with
    | Node(b,_,_,_,_) -> b
    | Leaf(b,_) -> b

let getAxis s =
    match s with
    | Node(_,_,_,_,a) -> a
    | Leaf(_,_) -> failwith "leaf ramt af axis"


//Get bounding box
let getBox s =
    match s with
    | Node(_,_,_,b,_) -> Some b
    | Leaf(_,b) -> Some b

let closestHit (triList : BasicShape.Triangle list) ray =
    let sndRects = List.map(fun x -> x:> Shape) triList
    let min = List.map(fun (x:Shape) -> x.hit ray) sndRects |> List.choose id
    match min with
    |[] -> None
    |_ -> Some(List.minBy (fun (di, nV, mat) -> di) min)

let searchLeaf leaf ray t' =
    match leaf with 
    | Leaf(s,_) -> let hit = closestHit s ray
               match hit with
               |Some(f,_,_) -> if (f<t') then Some hit else None
               |None -> None
    | Node(_,_,_,_,_) -> failwith "Expected leaf"

let order(d, left, right) =
    if d > 0.0
    then (left, right)
    else (right, left)

let rec search node ray t t' =
    match node with
    |Leaf(_,_) -> searchLeaf node ray t'
    |Node(_,_,_,_,a') -> 
        let direction = Ray.getDirection ray (fst a')
        let origin = Ray.getOrigin ray (fst a')
        let nodeValue = Point.getFromAxis (snd a') (fst a')
        if(direction) = 0.0 then
            printfn("%s") "flatsite"
            if(origin <= nodeValue) then search (getLeft node) ray t t'
            else search (getRight node) ray t t' 
        else 
            let tHit = (nodeValue - origin) / direction
            let (fst, snd) = order(direction,getLeft node, getRight node)
            if tHit <= t || tHit < 0.0 then
                search snd ray t t'
            else if tHit >= t' then
                search fst ray t t'
            else
             match search fst ray t tHit with
             |Some hit -> Some hit
             |_ -> search snd ray tHit t'


let traverse tree ray (bawx:BasicShape.BoundingBox) =
    match(bawx).hit(ray) with
    |Some(t,t') ->  search tree ray t t'  
    |None -> None


//Finding the midpoint in the triangles in Shapes-list - we do this (recursively) to find out what axis to split 
let rec mkTmKdtree (shapes : BasicShape.Triangle list) (box:BasicShape.BoundingBox) =               
     //Finding biggest dimension in the shapes list
    let axis = snd (box.getLongestAxis)
    let axisMidPoint = 
        let midPoint = List.fold (fun acc (ele:BasicShape.Triangle) -> (acc + ele.getMidPoint())) (Point.mkPoint 0.0 0.0 0.0) shapes
        let avgMid = midPoint / float(shapes.Length)
        avgMid 

    let rec largerThanSplit (xs:BasicShape.Triangle list) = 
        let results = List.choose(fun (elem:BasicShape.Triangle) ->
            match axis with
            |"x" -> if (Point.getX (elem.getMidPoint())) >= (Point.getX axisMidPoint) then Some elem else None
            |"y" -> if (Point.getY (elem.getMidPoint())) >= (Point.getY axisMidPoint) then Some elem else None
            |"z" -> if (Point.getZ (elem.getMidPoint())) >= (Point.getZ axisMidPoint) then Some elem else None) xs
        results 


    let rec lessThanSplit (xs:BasicShape.Triangle list) = 
        let results = List.choose(fun (elem:BasicShape.Triangle) ->
            match axis with
            |"x" -> if ((Point.getX (elem.getMidPoint())) <= (Point.getX (axisMidPoint))) then Some elem else None
            |"y" -> if ((Point.getY (elem.getMidPoint())) <= (Point.getY (axisMidPoint))) then Some elem else None
            |"z" -> if ((Point.getZ (elem.getMidPoint())) <= (Point.getZ (axisMidPoint))) then Some elem else None) xs
        results

    //Creating the left and right list from the above 
    let rightTest = largerThanSplit shapes
    let leftTest = lessThanSplit shapes

    //If one of the trees are empty, we add make left and right equivelant. 
    let left = if(leftTest.IsEmpty && rightTest.Length > 0) then rightTest else leftTest
    let right = if(rightTest.IsEmpty && leftTest.Length > 0) then leftTest else rightTest

    //Check for duplicates among the lists. 
    if(((float(left.Length+right.Length-shapes.Length)/float(shapes.Length)) < 0.4) && left.Length <> shapes.Length && right.Length<>shapes.Length) then 
      let leftTree = mkTmKdtree left (BoundingBoxL box axis axisMidPoint)
      let rightTree = mkTmKdtree right (BoundingBoxR box axis axisMidPoint)
      Node(shapes,leftTree, rightTree, (box),(axis,axisMidPoint))

    else Leaf(shapes, (box))
```

Comment: Good question. I know F# and I understand triangles but I am sure there are others here at the F# tag with me who can figure out your problem if we had a more though explaination of what you are trying to do. In other words don't assume we all know  bounding box, KD tree, Stanford Bunny, epsilon, etc.  Most of those are all new to me. If you can help those of us good with F# understand what you are doing, then we can look at the code and see if it is doing that. I am sure there are people who can answer this question as written, but I am not one of them.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :-) The concepts of are familiar to those working with ray tracing, but I can see why they are not trivial for others. I found that this link explains it quite well: https://blog.frogslayer.com/kd-trees-for-faster-ray-tracing-with-triangles/

Comment: Thanks for the link. You should put it in the question as people some times do not look at the comments.

Comment: I am pecking on this problem as I have time so don't expect me to have an answer anytime soon. It would help if you could supply test cases for each function, specifically the input values and the expected results. If you have not done that already then I would suggest that you do that. Also I am surprised this has not received close votes and it is clearly a `here is my code, please debug it`. Personally I am learning a lot about optimizing ray-tracing with this question and will probably continue to work on it even it does get closed.

Comment: not looking into it, but your `epsilon` seems quite big.

Comment: Try simplifying the problem. Remove all the triangles except 2 say.  Make them small or cross tree boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the responses! I turned out that the bug was in our reflections of the figures, and had nothing to do with the data structure of the program.

But thank you anyway! :-)